# Upload image to DB but get an Exception

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to upload an image to DB. i use `java servlet` for this purpose. but i got an exception

`HTTP Status 500 - Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided`

my jsp page:

```
<form action="uploadservlet" method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data">
           <input type="file" name="photo" size="50"/>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
        </form>
```

and my servlet post method is

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
                   HttpServletResponse response)
                  throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

            // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
            Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
            if (filePart != null) {
                // prints out some information for debugging
                System.out.println(filePart.getName());
                System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
                System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

                // obtains input stream of the upload file
                inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
            }
       }
```

Comment: Please the the answer of @BalusC in the question I mentioned above. You might have missed to annotate your servlet (you did not show the relevant code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet needs to be annotated with `@MultipartConfig` (i.e. `javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig`). The `@MultipartConfig` annotation allows the servlet to handle requests made using the `multipart/form-data` MIME type. Another option is to mark the DispatcherServlet with a "multipart-config" section in web.xml

You can also have a look at [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html) that provides greater flexibility.